# How to set temporary entitlements for IOKit properties?

Tags: objective-c, macos, sandbox, entitlements, appstore-sandbox

I'm using sandboxing in for my Mac app. I need to set a property to IOKit like so,

```
IORegistryEntrySetCFProperty(reg, CFSTR("IORequestIdle"), kCFBooleanTrue);
```

Because of app sandboxing, the system will not allow me to do it. If I turn off app sandboxing, the property is set properly.

The error message I get in the console is as follows,
`deny iokit-set-properties IORequestIdle`

Is there a way for me to set a temporary entitlement so that I can do this properly. If so, how do I go about doing so?

Comment: Hello Charles, I'm having the exact same issue. Did you end up finding a work around for what you were intending to do back then? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no.  If you could turn entitlements on and off as you please, then the sandbox serves no purpose.

Unfortunately, this probably means you cannot do what you are trying to do.  If there isn't a work around, then you won't be able to submit your app to the app store after March 1, 2012.